# I have a file with letters and numbers and I want to segregate out the numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with letters and numbers and I want to segregate out the numbers
I tried out the following code, but it fails:

```
n_file = open("text.txt","br+")
num = ""
while(1):
    cch = n_file.read(1)
    if(len == n_len):
        break
    if(cch != '\n'):
        n_len = n_len + 1
    if(re.findall("[0-9]", cch):
        num = num + text
print(num)
```

It says:

```
print("Check This",(int)cch)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: but i failed to find `print("Check This",(int)cch)` line on your program.

Comment: The brackets should be int(cch) on the error message you post.  But the code snippet you included is clearly incomplete and untestable -- you use several  variables that aren't defined in the snippet, like n_len, and you don't include the line that is an error.  The snippet as it is will not do what you want, but it's not even clear what you're trying to do.  Please include an accurate minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is invalid syntax because you are trying to do a cast a la Java. Try to print `int(cch)`.

By the way, why are you doing `while(1)` and then check if `len == n_len` to do a `break`? Why do you not use these values in the while itself? Like, `while(n_len < len)`

Apart from that, you can simplify a lot your code. Something like (I didn't try this code, so any bug just try to figure out what is happening):

```
    num = ''
    with open("text.txt","r") as file:
        for char in file.readline():
           if char.isdigit():
               num += char

    print int(num)
```

I don't know if you want to read the file until a limit len is achieved. if so you need to have a counter after the `char.isdigit()` and stop when this len is achieved. And close the file is always a good practice, I'm not seeing you closing it. The `with` statement do that for you.